# How to build a line chart using PHP and Google Charts?

Tags: php, google-visualization, unix-timestamp

I would like to create a line charts of orders on a per-hour basis so I can easily see when they were placed. But I'm seriously struggling to get all the data in a chart. I would like to use Google Charts since I have some familirity with it and avoid third-party functions/classes if possible.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// some more code here
function drawChart() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Time', 'Orders'],
     ['12:00',  $orders12],
     ['13:00',  $orders13],
     ['14:00',  $orders14],
     ['15:00',  $orders15],
     // etc for every hour in the day
   ]);
// some more code here
</script>




while ($objectTime = $objDB->getObject($result_time)) {
/*  PSUEDO CODE

if ($objectTime->entryDate) == [placed between 12:00 - 13:00]
    $orders12++;

if ($objectTime->entryDate) == [placed between 13:00 - 14:00]
    $orders13++;    
*/
}
```

As you can see, I don't know how to properly create the right variables to build the chart with. Should I use a variable for every hour (like I do now) and increment if an order matches that time? Or is there a smarter/better way?

Comment: Why dont you just echo data , ['12:00',<?php echo $orders12] ?>,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your data in an array of arrays, like this:

```
$myData = array(array('Time', 'Orders'), array('12:00', 5), array('13:00', 10), array('14:00', 16));
```

then you can output that to javascript like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($myData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>);
```

I would recommend following Robin Heller's advice to use the tools made available through SQL to do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can propably do is fetch the things in a fitting manner in first place. For example, when using MySQL

```
SELECT count(id) FROM `objects` WHERE timestamp < 12937 and timestamp > 12980
```

or use GROUP BY to further minimize the number of queries

```
SELECT count(id) FROM `objects` GROUP BY (timestampHour)
```

Apart from that, if you need the whole dataset anyways, storing a variable for every solution seems okay to me, although the use of Arrays is cleaner and easier to output (*foreach* instead of *echo*'ing every single variable)